# Tree nodes to Paths

Tags: java, list, data-structures, tree

I have a list of tree nodes following the order *Child*.*Parent* (e.g. 1.5).
I want to know the best java data-structure to use in order to convert this into paths?

For example the list below shows each node and its parent:

```
nodes= [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 2.4, 1.4, 1.5, 3.5, 4.6, 5.6, 6.7, 12.7, 7.8, 14.9, 7.9, 9.10, 8.10, 10.11, 5.12, 15.13, 12.13, 13.14, 3.15]
```

I want to use the list to build all possible paths. Here is an example of two paths, which will later be used to build the actual tree:

```
Path_1 = [0,1,4,6,7,8,10,11]
```

and

```
Path_2 = [0,1,5,6,7,9,10,11]
```

The numbers are references and do not represent the order so there could be a path showing 15 as the child of 13. There should be 15 paths in total for *nodes* example list above.

Please note that a path should always start from zero.

Thanks

Comment: Are the nodes stored as doubles? as strings? as a custom type?

Comment: They are stored as Strings

Comment: Did you try to use directed graphs as adjacency set in Java? After adjacency set is built, you can easily traverse and find the paths between 0 and 11 for instance.

Comment: _Note_: This is a __directed graph__, and not a __tree__.  The example given shows two paths between `0` and `11`, one going through node `4` and one going through node `5`.

Comment: Thanks guys that's very helpful, it narrows down my problem so now I need to get going with directed graphs.